# Disable all dates except a list of specific dates using MultiDatesPicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

I'm using [MultiDatesPicker for jQuery UI](http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/).

I have a list of dates and I want to enable only those dates and disable all others.

```
var a = ['11.11.11', '11.12.12', '11.12.13'];

$('.dates').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.y",
    beforeShowDay: function(a){
        _.each(a, function(date){
            return date ? [true, ''] : [false, '']
        })
    },
    separator: '.',
    maxPicks: 1,
});
```

This is not working. How can I accomplished this?

Comment: What is multiDatesPicker? You have given no context at all. I would suggest taking a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatpickr

Comment: Sorry, edited. using library.

Comment: Ok sorry, I don't use that library. But I (and many thousands of other people) do use the datepicker linked above, and you can enable dates with it pretty easily.

Comment: i have couple different libs as well, this one makes all i need, i just cant figure out how to make my task working (

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the example in the doc ?

http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/#demo-disable-dates

It seems that you have to pass an array of dates and not an array of strings.

Comment: yes i did, but there is no example for such case. I know how to disable all dates, but cannot find how to add mine (

Comment: also datepicker accepts date obj as well as a string